# FFMpeg how to add advance filters to Video

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

How to add advance filters like Snow rain to video using ffmpeg library.
I have visited: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html and https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FilteringGuide but cannot come to any conclusion reading these references.

Comment: [There are filtering examples available in the repo](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/tree/master/doc/examples). It's possible some of these examples may be out of date, though.

Comment: hi @Cornstalks i didnt get actual command line options to to execute like ffmpeg 'list of command ' can u help me here.

Comment: Are you asking how to do this via the command line with the `ffmpeg` program, or programmatically via libavfilter?

Comment: @Cornstalks through ffmpeg program u got it correct

Comment: Then I regret to inform you this question is off topic for Stack Overflow. You should ask this question on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Video Production](http://video.stackexchange.com/). Stack Overflow is for programming (which includes using the ffmpeg libraries like libavcodec and libavfilter, but not using the command line program).

Comment: @Cornstalks most command do work on Android as my question targets Android only but the command to execute I am not aware of. Does it make clear?

Comment: I understand your question, but just because you're running `ffmpeg` on an Android device doesn't make it on-topic for Stack Overflow. As I mentioned earlier, you should ask this question on Super User or Video Production.

Comment: @Cornstalks Thanks done here http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/20251/ffmpeg-how-to-add-advance-filters-to-video